# Hibernate: map a "many to one" on a "n:m" relationship

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I have two tables which are in 1:n relationship:

```
musician
{
id;
...
musician_status_id;
...
}

musician_status{
id;
name;
...
}
```

They are mapped in Hibernate:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "musician_status_id", nullable = false)
public MusicianStatus getMusicianStatus() {
   return this.musicianStatus;
}
```

Now my DB model changes to a n:m one.

```
musician
{
id;
...
...
}

musician_has_status{
musician_id;
status_id;
organisation_id;
...
}

musician_status{
id;
name;
...
}
```

I have a lot of queries and code which relay on the old mapping. Therefore i want that the Hibernate getter only returns a single musician_status depending on the organisation_id. My organisation_id is stored in static variable (login data).

I thought of a view and a interceptor to retrieve only the musician_status for a certain organisation_id. I don't really know how to achieve this in Hibernate...

Thank's in advance.

Added:
New DB Mapping would look like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "musician")
public Set<MusikerHasMusikerStat> getMusicianHasMusicianStatus() {
  return this.musikerHasMusicianStatus;
}
```

I want to change that to something like that:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "musician")
@Add a Filter or something like that?: where musician_has_status.organisation_id=LoginDat.getOrganisationID()
public MusicianStatus getMusicianStatus() {
  //or select the right status here?
  return this.musicianStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map it as it really is in the database, and change the code of the `getMusicianStatus` method:

```
@OneToMany(...)
@JoinColumn(...)
public void getStatusesWithOrganization() {
    return this.statusesWithOrganization();
}

/**
 * Returns the musician status for the organization stored in 
 * the static login data
 */ 
public public MusicianStatus getMusicianStatus() {
    for (StatusWithOrganization s : statusesWithOrganization) {
        if (LoginData.organizationId.equals(s.getOrganization().getId())) {
            return s.getMusicianStatus();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer: I thought on that but i think i can't use musician.musicianStatus = ... in Hibernate queries than, or?

Comment: No, you can't. You've changed the database schema and the way entities are associated. You'll have to refactor the code. You could also use a filter, but I get the feeling that you might regret it later, when you'll have to exploit the additional organization column. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters

Comment: thanks, i think a filter could be what I'm looking for. I added some code to the question for better understanding.

Comment: i looked through the filter docu but i think i can't get the Set<MusicianHasStatus> to a singel MusicianStatus. Or is there a way?

Comment: I don't know, because I have never used them. But if the where clause of the query makes sure that at most one row is ever returned, I don't see why you couldn't map the association as a ToOne association. The additional table is a join table, that must be filtered.

Comment: Hm, i'll try it. But the next problem is that i have to add the  organisation_id parameter to the hibernatesession but the organisation changes with the Login. There is no way to add a function (like in your code getMusicianStatus) to hibernate, so that I can use it in a query (like musician.getMusicianStatus)? @Anantha Sharma

Comment: That's why my answer suggests refactoring. Using filters looks like a hard to understand and hard to maintain hack. You'd have to find a way to configure the filter each time a session is created.

Answer (score 0):

Id's suggest you to use the `@Where( clause = "MYCONDITION" )` clause, since it will filter the data at the query level which will give you much better performance.

Comment: This would need the where clause to be a compile-time constant, which it's not, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: if the value needs to be sent dynamically we can use filters, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/filters.html this will ensure that we can restrict the loading of unwanted objects..

Comment: Yes, that's also what I suggested in one of my comments.

Comment: sorry mate.. didn't check the comment.. :)